# How to measure if performance is based on luck or skill?

Tags: distributions, correlation, bayesian, statistical-significance, model-evaluation

In Thinking Fast and Slow, Kahneman analyzed investment advisers' returns over eight years to see how consistently advisers performed over time. While he expected large variation in performance, he was surprised to see that the correlation was basically zero. "The results resembled what you would expect from a dice-rolling contest, not a game of skill," he writes.

What statistical tests did he use?

Here are the CSAT averages for 12 imaginary agents at Limitless Customer Support Ltd over 6 fortnights. CSAT is calculated based on an average of customer ratings, where customers give a 0 (horrible), 1, 2, or 3(awesome).

```
3.00    2.93    2.44    3.00    2.80    2.57
3.00    2.75    3.00    2.95    2.92    3.00
2.95    2.97    2.97    3.00    2.97    2.96
2.76    3.00    2.89    2.82    2.79    2.69
3.00    2.56    2.94    2.75    2.69    2.81
2.53    2.74    2.83    2.76    3.00    3.00
2.78    2.88    3.00    2.94    2.91    2.88
2.92    2.78    2.85    2.82    2.71    2.90
2.75    2.76    2.91    2.94    2.90    2.90
2.71    2.90    3.00    3.00    3.00    1.00
2.85    2.86    2.86    3.00    3.00    3.00
2.50    2.80    2.80    2.85    2.93    2.85
```

Here are the averages of the above (same 6 fortnights).
2.80    2.79    2.86    2.85    2.88    2.81

Do I need to give the amount of survey responses that go into the creation of each fortnightly CSAT before we can answer the question of whether performance is skill-based or luck-based?

Or can we already get a pretty good answer on the question of whether agents' CSAT is luck- or skill-based based on each agent's average CSAT per fortnight? (If the answer is 'yes', how do we do it?)

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Why are there 6 columns to represent performance over 5 fortnights?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what test Kahneman uses, but it seems to me this is basically just an ANOVA test. When we refer to an agent's "skill" we are referring to his expected performance, and when we talk about the amount of "luck" involve we are referring the variance about an agent's performance. We want to test whether there is an identifiable deviation in skill between agents, thus we want to test if at least one agent has a different mean, thus we should use an ANOVA.

I think Kahneman might be treating the agents as random rather than fixed effects, hence his discussion of "correlations" (inter-class v. intra-class correlations) rather than means.

(This interpretation suggests we shouldn't say that a game like this is either a game of luck OR a game of skill, but rather that there are components of skill (mean) and luck (variance) as in almost all games. Of course, if there can exist no difference in skill between players, then the game can be called exclusively luck-based).